How to properly make routes for a server with two internet connections (one behind NAT, second with public IP). Also add proper port forwarding
ubuntu 22 desktop. So Network Manager it is ;)
Initial conditions - 2 network interfaces.
Both with internet. One with a "public IP" and the second with a local network.
I want to make it so that all regular traffic goes through the regular internet.
And through the public IP, there would be port forwarding to an internal web server.
enp3s0 - regular local internet. 192.168.0.0/24 GW - 192.168.0.8 (yes, an odd router address) "Wired connection 1"
enp5s0 - public IP 199.199.199.231, - GW 199.199.199.225 "Wired connection 2" (since this is a public IP, I replaced it)
wg0 - wireguard.
I made the following settings (maybe someone will find this NetworkManager example useful)
sudo nmcli connection modify "Wired connection 1" ipv4.route-metric 100
sudo nmcli connection down "Wired connection 1" && sudo nmcli connection up "Wired connection 1"

sudo nmcli connection modify "Wired connection 2" \
ipv4.method manual \
ipv4.addresses 199.199.199.231/27 \
ipv4.gateway 199.199.199.225 \
ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"

echo "200 custom_table" | sudo tee -a /etc/iproute2/rt_tables 
ip route add default via 199.199.199.225 table 200  
sudo nmcli connection modify "Wired connection 2" +ipv4.routes "0.0.0.0/0 199.199.199.225 200"
sudo nmcli connection modify "Wired connection 2" +ipv4.routes "0.0.0.0/0 199.199.199.225 table=200"
sudo nmcli connection modify "Wired connection 2" +ipv4.routing-rules "priority 100 from 199.199.199.231/27 table 200"
sudo nmcli connection modify "Wired connection 2" ipv4.route-metric 200
sudo nmcli connection down "Wired connection 2" && sudo nmcli connection up "Wired connection 2"

Everything works perfectly as I wanted.
All outgoing traffic goes through enp3s0.
And incoming connections go to enp5s0 with the public IP.
But here's the question: I want to make 443 port forwarding to the local network. to 192.168.0.2:443
I'm doing it roughly like this:
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp5s0  -p tcp  --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2:443
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 199.199.199.231 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2:443
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.0.2 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp3s0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

(all default policies are accept for simplifying testing)
And this is where it doesn't work.
More precisely, it only works if I disconnect the first interface.
I tried debugging through tcpdump - I understood that packets arrive but don't return.
In general, something is wrong with the routing.
Specifically, it turns out that during Port forwarding, the return packet doesn't come from enp3s0
What can you suggest? I've already exhausted Claude 3.5 Sonnet with questions (by the way, I recommend it to everyone, it's currently the top neural network).
I have suggestions that we need to make two custom routing tables.
And somehow specify that enp3s0 and enp5s0 refer to each other.
The second is to do something with packet marking. But how will this work with return packets?

"connmark" can be used to "categorize" connections, so that you would be able to match with the connmark and set different (fw)mark, which allows you to route replies for requests that ingressed via different interfaces.
